# How do I get the GRPC Metadata sent by a client on the service implementation?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am able to obtain the Metadata using an interceptor on the channel so I can tell it is being sent.

```
.intercept(
  new ServerInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
        ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
        Metadata headers,
        ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

      System.out.println(headers);
      return next.startCall(call, headers);
    }
  })
```

But I was wondering how do I access it from a service implementation? Am I supposed to do some round about ThreadLocal work to pass it down?

This is different from [How to read Meta data in gRPC using Java at client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479217/how-to-read-meta-data-in-grpc-using-java-at-client-side) which talks about it on the client side.

Comment: Is this similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112374/how-do-i-access-request-metadata-for-a-java-grpc-service-i-am-defining/40113309 ?

Comment: The answer does not show it getting the meta data in the interceptor but that's minor I could forsee what needs to be used.  Also it is grouped under python rather than Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in the OP I was thinking it had to be some round about way.  I did get it to work, but does not seem "ergonomic"

Added two constants in my GrpcServer class. (Could be moved somewhere else)

```java
  public static Metadata.Key<String> JWT_CLAIMS_KEY =
      Metadata.Key.of("jwtClaims", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

  // The parameter value here is irrelevant and does not need to match the previous one, but useful for debugging.
  public static Context.Key<String> JWT_CLAIMS_CONTEXT_KEY = Context.key("jwtClaims");
```

The interceptor is added to the builder.

```
    .intercept(
      new ServerInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
            ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
            Metadata headers,
            ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
          final var context =
            Context.current()
              withValue(JWT_CLAIMS_CONTEXT_KEY, headers.get(JWT_CLAIMS_KEY));
          return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
       }
     })
```

The service implementation uses the `Context.get()` method to obtain the value.

```
  @Override
  public void echo(
      EchoOuterClass.EchoRequest request,
      StreamObserver<EchoOuterClass.EchoResponse> responseObserver) {

    System.out.println(GrpcServer.JWT_CLAIMS_CONTEXT_KEY.get());
    responseObserver.onNext(
        EchoOuterClass.EchoResponse.newBuilder().setMessage(request.getMessage()).build());
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
  }
```

I guess I was looking for something like...

```
.intercept(Contexts.serverInterceptorBuilder()
  .withMetadataValue(JWT_CLAIMS_KEY, JWT_CONTEXT_CLAIMS_KEY)
  .build();
```

And which would be implemented as something like (note not tested, just writing from my head...)

```
ServerInterceptorBuilder serverInterceptorBuilder() {
  return new ServerInterceptorBuilder(Context.current());
}
private static class ServerInterceptorBuilder {
  private Context context;
  ServerInterceptorBuilder(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
  public <X> ServerInterceptorBuilder withMetadataValue(
      Metadata.Key<X> metadataKey,
      Context.Key<X> contextKey) {
    context = context.withValue(contextKey, metadataKey);
    return this;
  }
  public ServerInterceptor build() {
    return new ServerInterceptor() {
      new ServerInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
            ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
            Metadata headers,
            ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
           
          return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
       }
    };
  }
}
```